# React Native: Array.map()-based rendered components not updating on state change

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I have a few components being rendered from an Array.map() that won't update even when the state (pertaining to said array) changes, and I have no clue why this is.

Home (main component) :

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { base } from './data';

import Indicator from './components/Indicator';

const Home = () => {
  const [switches, setSwitches] = useState(base);

  const handleToggle = (id: number) => {
    base.map(switch => {
      switch.on =
        (switch.on && switch.id !== id) || (!switch.on && switch.id === id)
          ? !switch.on
          : switch.on;
    });
    setSwitches(base);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {switches.map(switch => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleToggle(switch.id)}
          key={switch.id}
        >
          <Indicator
            color={switch.color}
            on={switch.on}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
```

Indicator component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

import { On, Off } from './Indicators';

interface IndicatorProps {
  color: string;
  on: boolean;
}

const Indicator: React.FC<IndicatorProps> = ({ color, on }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      {on ? <On /> : <Off />}
    </View>
  );
};

export default Indicator;
```

I have verified that the state of `switches` is changing as expected when clicking the touchable areas, but no visible change occurs in the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setState with an entirely new object so that it does not pass a shallow comparison.

You can do something like:

```
const handleToggle = (id: number) => {
  const newState = switches.map(switch => ({
    ...switch,
    on: (switch.on && switch.id !== id) || (!switch.on && switch.id === id) 
      ? !switch.on
      : switch.on
  }));
  setSwitches(newState);
};
```

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm not sure why, but when I tried to do it with the ternary `...` it didn't work, must have missed something. This works just fine though :)

Answer (score 0):

> I have verified that the state of switches is changing as expected

Are you 100% sure about this?

```js
    base.map(switch => {
      switch.on =
        (switch.on && switch.id !== id) || (!switch.on && switch.id === id)
          ? !switch.on
          : switch.on;
    });
    setSwitches(base);
```

This code doesn't toggle the switch value. `map` call calculates and returns the transformed array, but doesn't change it in place, and you then throw away the result, before calling `setSwitches` every time with exact same untoggled `base` value. In addition, you're toggling using `base`, when it looks like you probably want to toggle the state of `switches`.

You want something more like this:

```js
    setSwitches(switches.map(switch => {
      switch.on =
        (switch.on && switch.id !== id) || (!switch.on && switch.id === id)
          ? !switch.on
          : switch.on;
    }));
```

Comment: I thought it wouldn't either, but yes, I am 100% certain that the state is being updated.

Comment: Does the fixed code here work for you? There's a few different issues interacting (you're mutating the switch object too, for example, which might indeed change the state without affecting the react state) but I think this should work.

Comment: I had tried it previously, but it didn't work either.